# Login cookie timeouts on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, cookies

I'm just trying to figure out what the rules are regarding login cookie expirations on the site.

Is it that they expire on the 1st of the month, do they last for 1 month from the login, or do they *renew* for 1 month upon each use?

Because I seem to find that my login is always expired on the 2nd of the month (being in AU +10) might be why, but maybe it's just when I created my account.

Comment: Re *"AU"*: Do you mean [Australian Eastern Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Australia) (AEST; UTC+10:00)?

Comment: Fundamentally, this question is about Stack Exchange's login cookies; mentioning OpenID is merely tangential. This question is *not* off-topic as outdated due to OpenID deprecation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the answer here is still accurate, even after OpenID was deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our auth cookie is valid for 6 months from the time it is instantiated. You can check the cookie settings in your HTTP headers to see that. But in code:

```
Write(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(AppSettings.Site.CookieDurationMonths));
```

where

```
public static int CookieDurationMonths { get { 
    return Get("Site.CookieDurationMonths", 6); } }
```

As for how long your gmail, yahoo, myopenid, facebook, etc cookies last.. no idea. You'd have to ask them.

Comment: Courageous indenting.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem from December. Not sure what's wrong with the Google OpenID provider. However it immediately gets me authenticated once I click "log in"...